# mocha test function with mongoose call

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mocha.js, sinon

Having some problems unit testing the below code, I'm unsure whether it is possible or not due to the way it is coded.

> storeModel.js

```
var storeSchema = new Schema({
    storeId : { type: String, index: true},
    storeName : String
});
var model = mongoose.model('store', storeSchema);

var findStoresById = function(ids, callback) {
    model.find({ storeId: { $in: ids }}, function (err, result) {
        if (err) callback(err);
        callback(err, result);
    });
};

return {
    findStoresById: findStoresById,
    schema: storeSchema,
    model: model
};}();
```

Which i test like so..

```
it('will call "findStoresById" and return matched values [storeId: 1111] ', function (done) {

    storeModel.findStoresById(['1111'], function(err, store) {
        assert.equal(store[0].storeId, '1111');
        assert.equal(store[0].storeName, 'StoreName');
        assert.equal(err, null);
        done();
    });

});
```

However the problem when i implement the following code within a separate function:

```
get: function (req, res) {

    if (req.query.storeIds) {

        var ids = req.query.storeIds.split(',');

        storeModel.findStoresById(ids, function(err, stores) {
            if (err) {
                return res.send(err);
            }

            if (_.isEmpty(stores)) {
                var error = {
                    message: "No Results",
                    errorKey: "XXXX"
                }
                return res.status(404).json(error);
            }
            return res.json(stores);
        }); ...
```

How can i unit test this, i dont want to mock it as there is functionality in the "findStoreById" that needs testing, or is a refactor needed? suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand why you need this `return {
    findStoresById: findStoresById,
    schema: storeSchema,
    model: model
};}();` in your schema file. You can define the `findStoresById` function as a static function in your schema definition, and call it wherever you have access to it's model. The `storeSchema` can also be accessed as a property of the model.

Comment: can you show me an example of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd contest that you actually should be stubbing `findStoreById` because in not doing so `get` cannot strictly be unit tested, in that it's not isolated and could fail through no fault of its own. Seeing as the functionality you'd want to test lies within the callback of `findStoreById` and not the method itself, we can happily stub it and use the `yields` method of sinon to invoke its callback accordingly.

Note that, if you're testing routes, it's preferable to use [supertest](https://github.com/tj/supertest) else you'll have a lot of mocking of request and response methods on your hands. Therefore, for example:

```
var request = require('supertest');
var express = require('express');
// stub database method
sinon.stub(storeModel, 'findStoresById');

// create a test app/route to which we direct test requests
var app = express();
app.get('/', myRouteFunction);

it('sends a 404 error when no stores are found', function(done) {
  // use the second argument of `yields` to pass a result to the callback
  storeModel.findStoresById.yields(null, []);
  request(app).get('/').expect(404, done);
});

it('responds with any stores found', function(done) {
  // pass an array of found stores to the callback
  storeModel.findStoresById.yields(null, [{_id: 1}]);
  request(app).get('/').end(function(err, res) {
    if(err) return done(err);

    assert.deepEqual(res.body, [{_id: 1}]);
    done();
  });     
});
```

Comment: i couldnt get the stub.yields to work properly with supertest, it would skip my mock and use the actual method in my code.

that said i can still test it nicely with supertest just fine.. but perhaps you may know why the test didnt use my stub?

Comment: Without seeing your code, I am unsure why the stub would not work. Using it in conjunction with supertest shouldn't really make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is test `static's` and `method's` of certain Mongoose model, I would recommend you to use [sinon](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon) and [sinon-mongoose](https://github.com/gaguirre/sinon-mongoose).

But first, some tips for your code

```
var storeSchema = new Schema({
    storeId : { type: String, index: true},
    storeName : String
});

// 1) If you will callback with the same 'err' and 'result', pass the callback directly
function findStoresById(ids, callback) {
  // Instead of this...
  this.find({ storeId: { $in: ids } }, function (err, result) {
      if (err) callback(err);
      callback(err, result);
  });

  // Use this... it's the same, but shorter
  this.find({ storeId: { $in: ids } }, callback);
}

// 2) Declare a static method on your model, instead of export manually (see Monggose documentation for more info)
storeSchema.static('findStoresById', function (ids, callback) {
});

// 3) Create your model after the statics were declared, and use CamelCase
var model = mongoose.model('Store', storeSchema);

// 4) Export just your model
// If you want the model -> var Store = mongoose.model('Store')
// If you want the schema -> var schema = Store.schema
// If you want to call your method -> Store.findStoresById(...)
module.exports = model;
```

Then, to test the method `findStoresById`

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
require('sinon-mongoose');

var Store = mongoose.model('Store');

sinon.mock(Store)
  .expects('find').withArgs({ storeId: { $in: ['id1', 'id2'] } })
  .yields(null, 'SUCCESS!');

Store.findStoresById(['id1', 'id2'], function (err, res) {
  assert(res, 'SUCCESS!');
});
```

You can find working (and simple) examples on the [sinon-mongoose](https://github.com/gaguirre/sinon-mongoose) repo.

Comment: Thank you so much Gon! It helped me today